# IF Statement isn't working. Batch Files

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am a beginner at batch files. So I was making a basic batch file and when I tested it out, it said `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` But I am quite sure that it is correct. I knew it was in the IF parts of my coding, as I put several wait scripts(using VBS). I don't use REM just yet so I don't know what the problem is. What I wrote is something like this.

```
@echo off

b:
set a=1

IF %a%==1 goto :a

:a

echo Test

pause

goto :b
```

I also have quite alot of other `IF %variable%==number` statements in the coding and they all work fine. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your label `b` has the colon on the wrong side, turning it into a command that tries to set the default drive to your second floppy :-)

Secondly, although not strictly necessary, I prefer labels to be on their own line:

```
    @echo off
:b
    set a=1
    IF %a%==1 goto :a
:a
    echo Test
    pause
    goto :b
```

Running this results in:

```
C:\Users\Pax\Documents> testprog
Test
Press any key to continue . . . <ENTER>
Test
Press any key to continue . . . <ENTER>
Test
Press any key to continue . . . <ENTER>
Test
Press any key to continue . . . <CTRL-C>
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\Pax\Documents> _
```

Comment: Seems like it was a label issue. Though I do have another problem which I have a theory of. If you use the IF statement without the variable set to anything, will it not work? Thanks again.

Comment: Resolved the issue, the theory I had was correct. Sorry for the bother. :)

Comment: Variables set to nothing work okay. You only have to try `echo [%xyzz%]` to see that in action. You'll get the uninterpreted `[%xyzzy%]` if it's not set. If it's set to 1 (for example), you'll get `[1]`. In any case, your variable _was_ set in the code given.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF %a%==1 goto :a
```

Should be

```
IF %a%==1 goto a
```

For further help, here's where I found the solution: http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm
It has all the info you need.

Comment: This isn't correct, `goto` with the label containing the colon works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

*Like **paxdiablo** said it may not be necessary but it can help to give tags their own line and there can be other little things that may not be necessary but can help you be a bit organized  which will help you in the long run one way it can be fixed up is like so for a example.*

```
@echo off
:b
set a=1
IF %a%==1 goto a
:a
echo Test
pause
goto b
```

*Also the* `IF %a%==1 goto a` *can be changed to* `IF %a% EQU 1 goto a`
*just like the* `goto` *can be written as* `goto :a` ***or*** `goto a` *.
a Title can be added with* `Title title of window` *etc..*

*Happy exploring.*